# Use beta editor with inspect

Tags: xstate, xstate-react

I'm using inspect

```
inspect({
      iframe: false,
    });
```

Is it possible to pass a custom `url` to the `inspect` to use the new beta editor?

Also, is it possible to hide the sidebar when opening the visualizer?